# Creating multiple column layout with div's

Tags: css, html, layout, multiple-columns

I wanted to add a multiple column layout to one of my parent div's to display small widgets. I started of with 3 columns left, middle and right.

I tried to get the columns to display next to each other by using:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

But it didn't work [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/)

I also tried to use:

```
float: left;
```

But again no success [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U6Pj/2/)

I got it right by using:

```
display: table-cell
```

Now my problem is that when using this last method it sets a minimum width after which it would not scale any smaller and it adds a scroll bar to the bottom of the page which I do not want.

I would like to know why the first two methods did not work in my scenario as I have found other answers on SO that shows that the first two methods are possible solutions.

**CSS**

```
#left_widget_column {
border: 0px;
margin: 10px 65% 10px 2%;
padding: 0px;
width: 32%;
}

#middle_widget_column {
border: 0px;
margin: 10px 34% 10px 34%;
padding: 0px;
width: 31%;
}

#right_widget_column {
border: 0px;
margin: 10px 2% 10px 65%;
padding: 0px;
width: 32%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left_widget_column">
<h2>Widget 1:</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis suscipit venenatis tempor. Mauris sit amet consequat dui.</p>
</div>

<div id="middle_widget_column">
<h2>Widget 2:</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis suscipit venenatis tempor. Mauris sit amet consequat dui.</p>
</div>

<div id="right_widget_column">
<h2>Widget 3:</h2>
<p>Fusce felis nisl, egestas a dolor sit amet, mollis cursus diam. Nulla malesuada ullamcorper ante. Vestibulum pulvinar, metus a congue eleifend, magna eros mattis lectus, sed vestibulum neque augue vel risus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use these weird margins: http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/5/

Comment: @dfsq I needed more whitesapce between the columns that's why I had margins.

Answer (score 1):

you should not using:

```
margin: 10px 34% 10px 34%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/2/

when using `float:left` the next Div location inside previous div so that's not need margin or ...

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I need more whitespace between columns and on the left and right edges, that is the reason for the margins.

Comment: no problem, decrease the width and add `margin` but not using 34% just using 10px and 2%... check this : http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/6/

Comment: css margin calculated base previous div not windows edge

Comment: your fiddle is still a little bit weird because the 3rd column jumps to the bottom. I need it to scale to the windows size. I understand if the column jumps down when the screen size is less than 50px or 60px but it only jumps up when the window is about 500px an up.

Comment: i khow,that's just a example, just playing with witdh and margin, to get a actual size,also you can using `twitter bootstrap` to get better result,

Comment: playing with margin doesn't do anything, you have to completely remove it for the scaling to work properly. I figured that the margins is somehow screwing up the alignment, but why. +1 for all you help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 3 id's: 1 class for the layout is enough. You can add id later on to use it in js, for example.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/4/)

```
.col {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I used id's because the width of the columns will not always be the same and it uses jQueryUI. Will test your solution now.

Comment: So, remember that the width of columns should not be more then container's. col1.width + col2.width + col3.width !> container.width; Don't forget about margins too. (I've added box-sizing: border-box; so paddings are counted as width of column)

Comment: yes if you counted up my margins and widths you would have seen that it is 99%, because parent div has `1px` border.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not thought of using floats instead? Remove the margins.

```
#left_widget_column {
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
    width: 32%;
}

#middle_widget_column {
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 32%;
   float: left;
}

#right_widget_column {
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 32%;
    float: right;
}
```

See it here LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/Whysg/3/

Comment: If you look at my question you will see that I have tried to use `float: left;` on method 2. I also need whitespace between columns and on the edges.